# check if uuid is equally partitioned in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was trying to check if the uuid is equally partitioned in DB with below queries, The idea is to check the uuid between each range.However it didn't work with `error: Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.`.

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN id BETWEEN '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' AND '10000000-0000-0000-000000000000' THEN 0
    WHEN id BETWEEN '10000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' AND 'FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF' THEN 2
    ELSE -1
  END AS id_group,
  COUNT(*) AS num_records
  FROM dbo.students
  WHERE generate_time BETWEEN '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-01' 
  GROUP BY id ORDER BY id
```

I already check that the uuid is always valid by query: `select id, convert(uniqueidentifier, id) from dbo.students where id != convert(uniqueidentifier, id)`

Please advise what else I should try, thank you!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner `dbo` => SQL Server

Comment: sry, that was a typo. Please ignore it.

Comment: Okay, I've tagged the request with `sql-server` then.

Comment: Why are you trying to determine this experimentally? Those UUIDs are being generated by some method. That method should be well documented. It will either be using a deterministic method which may not be distinguishable by *your* tests or it may be using e.g. cryptographic randomness. But again, it should be well documented.

Answer (score 2):

`10000000-0000-0000-000000000000` and `FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF` are too short. A UUID is 32 hex digits.

---

Note that your groups are not evenly sized.

It might be simpler to filter inside a count.

```
SELECT
  COUNT( CASE WHEN id BETWEEN '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' AND '80000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' THEN 1 END) as group1,
  COUNT( CASE WHEN id BETWEEN '80000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001' AND 'FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF' THEN 1 END) as group2,
  COUNT(*) AS num_records
FROM students;
```